# How to call c++ application in Java using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have an existing c++ application which has a few API. I need to call those API in my Java program. I tried looking into a few sample apps online. But mostly all are creating a separate c++ application.

For example, in my current c++ app there is this API to getValue(). I want to call this getValue() method in Java using JNI.

This is the reference I am trying to follow.
[sample code (helloworld)](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)

My intention here is not to recreate the c++ application, I just want to have the JNI wrapper in between my c++ app and java program.

I am really sorry if this question is kinda dumb. This is my first time creating a JNI wrapper. So my question could be kinda dumb.

Currently this is how my Java code is:

```
public native void getValue();

static {
    System.loadLibrary(ValueClient);
}

public static void Main(String[] args) {
    Value value= new Value();
    value.getValue();
}
```

But the problem is, the main supposed to be in another java file. How can I call the getValue() api without calling this in the Main as above?

Comment: So the flow goes like this `[java code] --loads--> [shared library]` Then the `[java code] --calls--> [your JNI func] --which calls--> [c++ API func in the shared lib]`

Comment: So you need to write a JNI function that calls `getValue()` and you need to build the c++ component as a shared library.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025 - where you can find a sample of how to call C++ code from Java via JNI.

Comment: @Oo.oO thanks for the sample code. spartygw thanks for the flow. I think i know how to do it now.